# How to stop the multiplying sum of same value reptedly without entering any values in that column in SQL using full join and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, left-join, full-outer-join

I have two tables T1 & T2 and two same columns in both tables C1 & C2 I am doing the subtraction of sum of two columns using full join and group by but when I adding the value in T1.C2 or T2.C2 the other columns value is multiplying automatically. I want to stop this multiplication please help me

My query is

```
Select T1.C1,(Sum(T1.C2)-Sum(T2.C2)) 
from T1 
Full join T2 on T1.C1=T2.C1 
group by T1.C1;
```

When I entering the value 1000 in T1.C2 & 100 in T2.C2 the subtraction is happening right my Output is

```
___________ 
|C1   C2.  |
|          |
|A   900   |
|          |
```

But When I entering 1000 again in C1.C2 the the output came wrong

```
____________
|C1  C2.   |
|          |
|A   1800  |
|          |
```

Expected output is 1900

Comment: Just to be clear.  Two tables with the same column name. T1.C1 has 2 rows of 1000.  T2.C1 has 2 rows of 100?

Comment: No sir T2.C1 has only one row of 100 please help me

Comment: You're joining on the same columns which are being summed, is there not a common key column between the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
select T1.C1,
       sum(T1.C2) - (Select isnull(sum(T2.C2), 0) From T2 where T1.C1 = T2.C1)
From T1
group by T1.C1
```

Output:

```
A  1900
```

Comment: Thanks iceblade this is working fine. How to show the value if only one column is filled T1.C1

Comment: You just need to add isnull for that case, I updated the query.

Comment: @NageshRaoNemmaniwar: this is a `left join`, while you started the question with a `full join`. They do not do the same thing. If there are "missing" rows in `t2`, they will not appear in the result, does that fit your use case?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you're looking for

```
select
    (select sum(t1.C1) from (values (1000), (1000)) T1(C1))-
    (select sum(t2.C1) from (values (100)) T2(C1));
```

Results

```
1900
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow unmatched rows in both tables, then a `full join` is the way to go. I would recommend pre-aggregating in subqueries first to avoid multiplying the rows:

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.c1, t2.c1) c1, 
    coalesce(t1.c2, 0) - 
    coalesce(t2.c1, 0) c2
from (select c1, sum(c2) sum_c2 from t1) t1
full join (select c1, sum(c2) sum_c2 from t2) on t1.c1 = t2.c1
group by coalesce(t1.c1, t2.c1)
```

If you want rows from both tables, then use an `inner join`, or a `left join` if you want all rows from one table, and all matched rows from the other one:

```
select 
    t1.c1,
    t1.c2 - coalesce(t2.c1, 0) c2
from (select c1, sum(c2) sum_c2 from t1) t1
left join (select c1, sum(c2) sum_c2 from t2) on t1.c1 = t2.c1
group by t1.c1
```